# Is there a way to make a anti-spam bot, that only applies to 1 person?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

(**This question is about a discord server bot**)

So i found this on the internet: (anti-spam bot)

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    //let's use something like a spam variable for 10 or more messages sent within 5000ms
    if(message.content === spam) {
     message.reply("Warning: Spamming in this channel is forbidden.");
     console.log(message.author.username + " (" + message.author.id + ") has sent 10 messages or more in 5 seconds in " + message.channel.name + ".");
    }

});
```

But is it possible to make a anti-spam bot that only applies to 1 person?

Reason: inside joke with some friends of mine, 1 is spamming a lot and we want him to get punished for it, and we dont want to punish others, so he will stop spamming.

Thank for the help! appreciate it a lot :D.

-Wisple

Comment: Is it just me who doesn't get how this code above should be an anti-spam bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a message is sent by a certain user by grabbing their ID. If you're in discord developer mode (you can turn it on in settings) you can right click on a user and hit 'Copy ID' to get their ID. From there you can change the if statement to something like

```
if (message.content === spam && message.author.id === "ID_HERE") {
```